# Получить дату заданного дня недели, исходя из текущей даты Carbon Laravel

Tags: laravel, carbon

На основании текущей даты Carbon::now(), нужно получить дату из текущей недели по порядковому номеру дня в недели от 1 до
7 или по названию дня недели (Monday, Tuesday...).

Пример:

- Допустим текущая дата: 2020-12-12;
- Мне необходимо узнать какая дата будет для Воскресенья текущей недели по названию Sunday или по номеру дня недели 7;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ на англоязычном stackoverflow, все довольно просто:

```
new Carbon("Sunday")
```